# Use HTML class and id etc on HTML code created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I have made a search-system where I can search for different artifacts on its names, date etc.
First I created it static with all the data in HTML, and then used a script I found ([listjs.com](http://listjs.com)) that did all the sorting and filtering etc.

However now I want to connect it to a database, and get all the data from this DB.
I managed to post and show the data in the list like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < artifacts.rows.length; i++) {
    var pic = artifacts.rows.item(i).APicture;
    var name = artifacts.rows.item(i).AName
    var city = artifacts.rows.item(i).ACity
    var date = artifacts.rows.item(i).ADate
    var type = artifacts.rows.item(i).AType

    list += '<li><table class="arti"> \
            <tr> \
                <td><img src="' + pic + '" width="60" height="60"></td> \
                <td><a id="crownID" class="name" href="#"><b>' + name + '</b></a></td> \
                <td><a class="city">' + city + '</a></td><a class="time" style="display:none;">-2000</a></td> \
                <td><a>' + date + '</a></td> \
                <td><a class="type">' + type + '</a></td> \
            </tr> \
            </table> \
        </li>';
}//end for

list += '</ul>';

document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML=list;
```

BUT now my list.js script do not work on my data. Probably because the HTML-tag is not actually HTML but JavaScript. 
I know it is possible to create SQL queries with `SORT BY` etc but since I already got a working program, it would be nice not to spend more time on it.

Anyone know a way to do this or if it is even possible?

Comment: Just a tip: an HTML id should have a unique value within your whole HTML document. So, the `id="crownID"` inside a loop isn't very clean :)

Comment: thanks, that id should come from my DB and not be static. It all went a little quick :)

Comment: what does 'do not work on my data' mean? What error are you getting?

Comment: data = content, sorry for not being specific

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you try to modify/access the list before you've returned your results to the document.

You can't access anything before it's actually written (by script or static, doesn't matter) to the document.

Check your command order:

1. build list
2. print to document
3. modify

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but the content is loaded from the database onload from the body of the HTML-script. After this all the sorting methods etc appear in HTML.